# Activity ResultCrash, Android Studio, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult

I am adding social logins to my app (I am learnng coding for android in Kotlin) I have facebook loging in and Twitter logging in but i have to comment out one or the other in the ActivityResult. is there a way to have both uncommented.

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    loginButton!!.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

The first one is facebook and the second is Twitter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different `requestCode`s, something like:

```
companion object {
    private const val CODE_FB = 100
    private const val CODE_TWITTER = 101
}
```

Pass `CODE_FB` when you `startActivityForResult()` for Facebook, and use `CODE_TWITTER` for Twitter.

Inside your `onActivityResult()`, filter by the request code:

```
when (requestCode) {
    CODE_FB -> callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    CODE_TWITTER -> loginButton!!.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```